# How to solve a differential equation solved constraints

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example,

Given that $y' - \frac{1}{t-1} = 0.$

The constrains are:

$$y(2) = -10 \space \space \space y(2) = 0 \space y(5) = 10$$

How would you solve such differential equation?

It's not a homework, it's a sample exercise from a book.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: $y(2)$ can be equal to $-10$ and $0$ at the same time...Please clarify your question.

Comment: @user37238 It seems to be wierd to me also, but that is what written on the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $y$ is a function of $t$. Since you have $y'(t) = \frac{1}{t-1}$, you have
$$y(t) = \int\frac{1}{t-1}dt = \ln (t-1) + C$$ for some $C\in\mathbb R$. You can now calculate $C$ from the initial conditions. For example, if the condition is $y(2) = -10$, you have
$$-10 = y(2) = \ln(2-1) + C = C$$
and therefore $C=-10$. This means that $y(t) = \ln(t-1)-10$

Comment: Good attempts +1

Answer (score 0):

If
$$y'-\frac{1}{t-1}=0$$
then
$$y'=\frac{1}{t-1}$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $t$:
$$\int y' dt = \int \frac{dt}{t-1}$$
$$y(t)=\ln\left|t-1\right|+C$$
If $y(2)=-10$ then
$$y(2)=\ln\left|2-1\right|+C=0+C=-10$$
and $C=-10$. Thus
$$y(t)=\ln|t-1|-10$$